# ImportError: No module named sklearn

Tags: 14.04, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I installed scikit-learn on  following these [instructions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#install-official-release)

Even when I try now to run again: `sudo pip install -U scikit-learn`

I get this message proving again that installation is ok:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /home/begueradj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But I fail to import it:

```
begueradj@begueradj-Sampo:~/Desktop/begueradj$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The Ubuntu 14.04 package is named python-sklearn (formerly python-scikits-learn) and can be installed in Ubuntu 14.04-19.04 using the following command:

```
sudo apt install python-sklearn
```

The python-sklearn package is in the default repositories in Ubuntu 14.04 as well as in other currently supported Ubuntu releases.

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later the Python 3 version of python-sklearn can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories with the following command:

```
sudo apt install python3-sklearn
```

Comment: python-sklearn is in the default Ubuntu repositories for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu at least up to Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: And what about 16.04 ?

Comment: python-sklearn is available from the default Ubuntu repositories in all currently supported Ubuntu releases up to 19.04. In 19.10 and later .only the python3-sklearn package is in the default Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 7):

When installing on Ubuntu Linux you have to have to install dependencies first using `apt-get`, then use a `pip install` otherwise the normal `pip install` of scikit-learn won't work properly. See below:

**Step 1: Make sure apt-get is updated**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Step 2: Install dependencies**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-numpy python-scipy libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base
```

**Step 3: pip install Scikit Learn**

```
pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a lot of things but finally, including uninstall with the automated tools. So, I've uninstalled manually scikit-learn.

```
sudo rm -R /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn
sudo rm -R /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.20.0-py3.6.egg-info
```

And re-install using pip

```
sudo pip3.6 install -U scikit-learn
```